# Search for Online Sockets in AS3

Tags: sockets, actionscript-3

PLATFORM : AIR for Android

im trying to develop a quick search algorithm for search online sockets on my LAN network.

the first algorithm was creating 255 sockets base on my gateway

EXAMPLE:

192.168.1.1 is my gateway

so i'll have to create sockets and connect 192.168.1.0 up to 192.168.1.254 in searching for online sockets. This is quick in searching, however it causes lags because it eats a lot of RAM. Even after i dispose the sockets that have failed to connect. All sockets that are online are stored in a Vector array.

i dispose the failed sockets by:

> 1. removing all listeners from the socket.
> 2. closing the socket
> 3. setting the socket to null.
> 4. Call `System.gc()` to force garbage collection

The second algorithm was using only 1 socket and it will start to connect starting from 192.168.1.0 and increments up to 255 until it finds a online socket. When the socket fails to connect, it will proceed to the next ip depending on the timeout.

```
var ip = '192.168.1';
var ipCounter = 0;

socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

socket.timeout = 50;

function connectHandler(e:Event):void{

}

function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
    ipCounter += 1;
    if(ipCounter > 255){
        ipCounter = 0;
    }
    socket.connect(ip+'.'+ipCounter.toString(), 18765);
}

socket.connect(ip+'.'+ipCounter.toString(), 18765);
```

this works however, it is slow.

How can i improved the search algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a faster solution.

I used `DatagramSocket` (UPD) instead for searching.

It's because it doesn't have to connect to a socket server to send data.

`datagramSocket.send(bytearray, start, length, ip, port);`